# In right triangle $ABC$, $AC=BC$, arc $DEF$'s center is $A$, if the two shaded segments have the same area, what is $AD:DB$?

Tags: circles

[image: Diagram]

I'm working on this question for a math class I'm taking. I don't think it's very hard, but for some reason I can't really get anywhere with it. Since triangle $ABC$ is 45-45-90, I called $AD$ $x$ and $BD$ $y$, then drew line segment $AE$ and tried to find the areas of the shaded regions and set them equal to each other, but I had too many variables.

Comment: If the shaded areas are equal then the area of the segment of the circle ADF equals the area of the right-angled triangle ABC.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem. What did you get for the answer?

Comment: $1:\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}-1$

Comment: Yeah that's what I got